# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined (Dropdown not working)

Tags: javascript, html

I've my live website. please visit on [Here](http://pushtiyouth.org/index.html)

When I am in any menu at the top corner like,  "About Us", "Contact Us", That time when I clicked "More" then it works but When I am on Home that time "More" doesn't work. please guide me.
You can see the code by Inspect element and that javascript name is custom.js.

Thanks in advance ☺

Comment: It seems you have outsourced data critical for the understanding of your question. Please remember to provide all necessary data (code, configuration data, exception name ...) in **the question itself**. If the link dies or changes your question will lose most if not all of its meaning!

Answer (score 0):

the "more" link has href="#" so when the event executed

```
$('.navbar-nav li a').bind('click', function(event) {
  var $anchor = $(this);
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
  }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

$($anchor.attr('href')).offset() returns undefined;
You need to remove event from the dropdown toggle button:

`$('.navbar-nav li a:not(.dropdown-toggle)').bind('click', function(event) {`

Answer (score 0):

Can be solved by not assigning the click event to the dropdown:

```
$('.navbar-nav li:not(.dropdown) a').bind(........
```